# Flutter gives "FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations" error when I try to run without debugging

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

When I try running my app without debugging. The app gives me the following error and proceeds with the installation(I'm using my phone via USB Debugging to test my app).

```
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1901 in debug mode...
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-9.1.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\analytics\FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

And when I enter my registered details(I have already created an account on my app) on the login page and click login , it gives me an authentication error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is caused due to outdated packages in your flutter project.
To solve the errors, do the following :

Step 1: Run the command `flutter pub outdated` in the terminal of your development environment. This command will find and display the list of packages that can be updated.

Step 2: Run the command `flutter pub upgrade` in the terminal of your development environment. This command will update the outdated packages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but sure it's not about the outdated packages. I got the same warning with latest package.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the mentioned packaged. We can simply upgrade the package to the latest version.

Or if possible can replace the package.

> flutter pub outdated

The above command can be used to check which packages are outdated or have an update.