# I can no longer read data from cloud firestore database which was previously showing in the list view

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project that have data in cloud firestore database. It was showing in my list view but for sometime now the result in the list view is error. My checks show that arraycontains + wherein have been remove from firestore. Am new and i don't know what to do .Can any one help me.

This is my repository

```
final forumRepositoryProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return ForumRepository(firestore: ref.watch(firestoreProvider));
});

class ForumRepository {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore;
  ForumRepository({required FirebaseFirestore firestore})
      : _firestore = firestore;

  FutureVoid createForum(ForumModel forumModel) async {
    try {
      var forumDoc = await _forums.doc(forumModel.name).get();
      if (forumDoc.exists) {
        throw 'Forum with the same name already exist';
      }
      return right(
          _forums.doc(forumModel.name).set(forumModel.toMap()));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.message!));
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  } 

  Stream<List<ForumModel>> getUserForum(String uid) {
    return _forums
        .where('members', arrayContains: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) {
      List<ForumModel> forums = [];
      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        forums
            .add(ForumModel.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
      }
      return forums;
    });
  }

  Stream<ForumModel> getForumByName(String name) {
    return _forums.doc(name).snapshots().map((event) =>
        ForumModel.fromMap(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }

  Either<Failure, dynamic> editForum(ForumModel forumModel) {
    try {
      return right(
          _forums.doc(forumModel.name).update(forumModel.toMap()));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  FutureVoid joinForum(String forumName, String userId) async {
    try {
      return right(_forums.doc(forumName).update({
        'members': FieldValue.arrayUnion([userId])
      }));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  FutureVoid leaveForum(String forumName, String userId) async {
    try {
      return right(_forums.doc(forumName).update({
        'members': FieldValue.arrayRemove([userId])
      }));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  Stream<List<ForumModel>> searchForum(String query) {
    return _forums
        .where(
          'name',
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query.isEmpty ? 0 : query,
          isLessThan: query.isEmpty
              ? null
              : query.substring(0, query.length - 1) +
                  String.fromCharCode(
                    query.codeUnitAt(query.length - 1) + 1,
                  ),
        )
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) {
      List<ForumModel> forums = [];
      for (var forumModel in event.docs) {
        forums.add(ForumModel.fromMap(
            forumModel.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
      }
      return forums;
    });
  }

  Either<Failure, dynamic> addMods(String forumName, List<String> uids) {
    try {
      return right(_forums.doc(forumName).update({
        'mods': uids,
      }));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  Stream<List<Upload>> getForumUploads(String name) {
    return _uploads
        .where('forumName', isEqualTo: name)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (event) => event.docs
              .map(
                (e) => Upload.fromMap(
                  e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>,
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        );
  }

  CollectionReference get _uploads =>
      _firestore.collection(FirebaseConstants.uploadCollection);

  CollectionReference get _forums =>
      _firestore.collection(FirebaseConstants.forumCollection);

  //    CollectionReference get _groups =>
  //    _firestore.collection(FirebaseConstants.groupCollection);
}

When i query the cloud_firestore data base with flutter riverpod nothing shows in the listview and this is the code

class ForumList extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String name;
  const ForumList({super.key,
    required this.name,
  });

  void navigateToCreateForum(BuildContext context) {
    Routemaster.of(context).push('/create-forum');
  }

  void navigateToForum(BuildContext context, ForumModel forumModel) {
    Routemaster.of(context) .push('${forumModel.name}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Create a forum',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )),
            leading: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onTap: () => navigateToCreateForum(context),
          ),
          ref.watch(userForumProvider).when(
                data: (forums) => Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: forums.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final forumModel = forums[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(forumModel.avatar),
                        ),
                        title: Text('${forumModel.name}',
                            style:
                                const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        onTap: (() {
                         // navigateToChatScreen(context, forumModel);
                           navigateToForum(context, forumModel);
                        }),
                        subtitle: Text('${forumModel.description}'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                error: (error, stackTrace) =>
                    ErrorText(error: error.toString()),
                loading: (() => const Loader()),
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

but when i query without flutter riverpod i was able to retrieve some data from cloud_firestore database. And this is the code

class ForumList extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String name;

  const ForumList({super.key, required this.name});

  void navigateToCreateForum(BuildContext context) {
    Routemaster.of(context).push('/create-forum');
  }

  void navigateToForum(BuildContext context, ForumModel forumModel) {
    Routemaster.of(context) .push('${forumModel.name}');
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
   
    final forumStream =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('forums').snapshots();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(''),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add))
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: forumStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('No data yet');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          var docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const MobileChatScreen(
                                name: 'name',
                              )));
                },
                
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: const CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/abstract-stained-pattern-rectangle-background-blue-sky-over-fiery-red-orange-color-modern-painting-art-watercolor-effe-texture-123047399.jpg'),
                      
                    ),
                    title: Text(docs[index]['name']),
                    
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child:const Icon(Icons.attach_file),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MobileChatScreen(name: name),
              
            ),
            
          );
        },
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have google but did not find any suitable help. The only thing i found out is that firebase have remove query of arrayContainsAny with whereIn. i will be very gratefull if i can be helped.

Comment: The `array-contains-any` and `in` operators are both still documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any You say: "My checks show that arraycontains + wherein have been remove from firestore." Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: My debug console show the following error  AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.8.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest versions of the FlutterFire plugins? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777998/flutter-gives-flutterfirebaseanalyticsplugin-java-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-oper (different plugin, but same error message)

Comment: I have upgraded all the dependences but the error is still there. I have even opened a new project with the latest dependences but the error is still there.

Comment: When i google the error it took me to cloud_firestore/flutter packages and if you check update 4.8.4 this is what it says 'FIX(firestore): remove assertion for arrayContainsAny & whereIn query combined (#11342). (199e1fc4)'. I don't know if this might be the cause of the problem

Comment: Hmm... that doesn't immediately ring a bell. I hope somebody else spots what may be going on here.

Comment: I am able to read data from firestore data base without flutter riverpod package but when i user the riverpod it doesn't show in the list view

Comment: OK, that's definitely interesting. I recommend adding that information to your question, possibly showing the minimum code that works - and then how it breaks when add riverpod.

Comment: I have updated the question so kindly look at it for me. Thanks

Comment: I'm not a Riverpod user myself, so hope somebody else spots the problem.